# Camel Endpoint URI using sql containing date range

Tags: apache-camel, camel-sql

I specified an endpoint containing a URI for a sql component as:

```
<endpoint id="select-myS" uri="sql:select myField from myView where ChangeDate between :#startDate and :#endDate"/>
```

I am setting startDate and endDate as headers.
In that case I receive the error message as:
*com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'between'*

If I try to avoid between, and add two clauses as below:
ChangeDate >= :#startDate and ChangeDate <= :#endDate, I receive other error:
 *The value of attribute "uri" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character*

(I also tried :#endDate>=ChangeDate , and it also not work! :-( ).

Could you please advise on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using XML to describe your route and endpoints, you have to escape your '>' and '<'chars, eg:

```
> should be escaped as &gt; (aka greather than)
< should be escaped as &lt; (aka lower than)
```

Which gives:

```
<endpoint uri="sql:... where ChangeDate &gt;= :#startDate and ChangeDate &lt;= :#endDate">
```